# How was this derivative simplified further?

Tags: calculus

Here is the steps on how the derivative gets simplified:

We are given the point (0,0) for it to be evaluated at.
\begin{align*}\tan(3x+y) &= 3x \\
(3+y^{\prime}) \sec^2(3x+y) &= 3 \\
y^{\prime} &= \frac{3-3\sec^2(3x+y)}{\sec^2(3x+y)} \\
&= \frac{-3\tan^2(3x+y)}{\tan^2(3x+y)+1} \\
\qquad&=-3\sin^2(3x+y)
\end{align*}
and this is where I get confused! How does it further get simplified to this:}
\begin{align*}& = \frac{-27x^2}{9x^2+1}\end{align*}
Is the point used to simplify it further? Is it a trig identity or  formula that they are using?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\tan(3x+y) = 3x
$$
Then 
$$
 \frac{-3\tan^2(3x+y)}{\tan^2(3x+y)+1}=\frac{-3 (3x)^2}{(3x^2)+1}== \frac{-27x^2}{9x^2+1}
$$

Comment: How are the tangents removed?

Comment: $\tan(3x+y)$ is replaced by $3x$.

Comment: My god, I can't believe I couldn't see this. Thanks for your help!